# compile lan messenger on windows

Tags: windows, compile

I am trying to compile lan messenger on windows. However, while building the lmc lib, I'm stuck at a point where the it shows an error:

```
openssl/rand.h no such file or directory.
```

If someone has already successfully compiled it on windows please help me out on it.

Comment: Do you have such file?

Comment: no, I do not have it and I don't know what lib/package does it belong to

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need OpenSSL development package, seems that Lan Messenger source code does not come with it.

When someone posts a source code, is normal that third party libraries does not come with it and have to be installed manually.

Here you can find detailed instructions on how to compile it properly: http://lanmsngr.sourceforge.net/forum/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=5#p8

Comment: yes, it was that. I downloaded the compiled binary and successfully compiled it. However, there is one more issue in lmcapp. It says that qtsingleapplication.h is missing. I have checked it and the file is in my project folder. It is strange as I am unable to build even though the file is there. any idea ?

Comment: Post a copy of the error, so I can find what happens. Thanx for accepting the answer.

Comment: shared.obj:-1: error: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__GetUserNameW@8 referenced in function "public: static class QString __cdecl Helper::getLogonName(void)" (?getLogonName@Helper@@SA?AVQString@@XZ)

Comment: This is yet another error I am facing. I successfully built the lib but when trying to build the main application it gives me this error. I assume that this error is due to main application is not properly recognizing the lib file

Comment: Yes, when you build an application that uses another library, you have to link it. What command are you using to compile?

Comment: I resolve it myself. it was missing advapi32.lib. Thanks anyway